# I'm can't access the key and value from a function that returns an IQueryable in winform that i took from a repository class

Tags: c#

i'm new in programming and i'm working on a Windows form application. I made a repostory class for all my dataBase work. I made a function in the repository that returns an IQueryable- it returns a key value pair.(key=dayOfWeek and value=revenue). Then when i called this function in the Form, because i wanted the information to be printed on labels, i cannot access the key seperately and the value seperately. It only gives me the option of the the whole key value pair.
this is my code in the repository class:

```
 public class ReportsRepository
    {
       FruitStoreDataContext db;
       public IQueryable RevenuePerDayOfWeek(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
       {
           db = new FruitStoreDataContext();
       var sumPerday = from s in db.OrderDetails
                       where s.Order.OrderDate >=startDate && s.Order.OrderDate <=endDate
                       select new
                       {
                           day = s.Order.OrderDate.DayOfWeek,
                           revenue = s.Price * s.Quantity
                       };

       var totalSumPerday = from f in sumPerday
                            group f.revenue by f.day into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Day= g.Key,
                                Sum = g.Sum()
                            };

       return totalSumPerday;
   }

 private void Report1Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportsRepository report = new ReportsRepository();
            var totalSumPerday = report.RevenuePerDayOfWeek(dateToStart, dateToEnd);
           int[]numOfDays = new int[7];


        for (DateTime day = dateToStart; day <= dateToEnd; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {

            dayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt32(day.DayOfWeek);
            numOfDays[dayOfWeek]++;

        }
        Label label;
        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
        int t = 0;

        foreach(var totalSum in totalSumPerday)
        {

            if (numOfDays[dayOfWeek] == 0)
                numOfDays[dayOfWeek] = 1;
            int y = (38 * t) + 60;
            label = new Label();
            label.Location = new Point(34, y);
            label.Visible = true;
            label.Size = new Size(450, 35);
            label.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            label.ForeColor = Color.White;
            label.Font = new Font("Lucida Console", 16);
            dayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt16(totalSum.Day.Key);

         //on the line below the word 'Day' and 'Sum' are underlined red...it doesn't give me the option to do that. I can only access the whole thing together(key,value)
            label.Text = totalSum.Day.ToString() + " : " + (totalSum.Sum / numOfDays[dayOfWeek]).ToString();
            labels.Add(label);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label);
            t++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You can do one query to achieve your result. Second, you don't need to return `IQueryable` as you want in-memory data only (with not further querying). So what you can do is:

```
public Dictionary<int, decimal> RevenuePerDayOfWeek(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    db = new FruitStoreDataContext();

    var sumPerday = (from s in db.OrderDetails
                     where s.Order.OrderDate >= startDate && s.Order.OrderDate <= endDate
                     group s by s.Order.OrderDate.DayOfWeek into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         Day = grp.Key,
                         Sum = grp.Sum(a => a.Price * a.Quantity)
                     }).ToDictionary(x => x.Day, x => x.Sum);

    return sumPerday;
}
```

Usage in `Report1Form_Load`:

```
var totalSumPerday = report.RevenuePerDayOfWeek(dateToStart, dateToEnd);

foreach (var totalSum in totalSumPerday)
{
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = totalSum.Key;
    decimal sum = totalSum.Value;

    // continue your code
}
```